# Tab to first field of subform in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, subform, tab-ordering

In MS Access, how can I tab form the last field of the main form to the first field on the first subform? As it is, wen I tab form the last field of the main form it moves to the last used field (usually the last field) of the first subform. Similarly, from the last field of the first subform it tabs to the last used field og the second subfor in stead of the first field on the second subform.
Not a big thing, but I reckon it should be relatively easy to address.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `On Enter` and `On Exit` subform events for set focus on required field in main form

Comment: I'm relatively new to Access, so I don't know what you mean by 'subform events'.

Comment: Click on subform in design mode, open properties, go to tab Events. In event you can use macro or VBA code `Me.MyControlName.SetFocus`